# "...or in a Close button in a child window."

Tags: winapi

MSDN - "WM_NCHITTEST" - "HTSYSMENU: In a window menu or in a Close button in a child window."

Can somebody give the example of a child window with Close button in HTSYSMENU area?

Answer (score 0):

An [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632591(v=vs.85).aspx) child window is the only thing I can think of.

[image]

Comment: No, MDI child's Close button isn't in the HTSYSMENU area.

Comment: @kero: You can double-click the `HTSYSMENU` to close the window, that's standard Windows behaviour.

Comment: But, Jonathan, standard HTSYSMENU area isn't "Close button" :)

Comment: That's what that text means. You will never see it look like an actual close button (except in Windows 3.1, which is when that text was probably written). A child window doesn't have a window menu in `HTSYSMENU` but it can have close button functionality if you double-click it.

Comment: 1) Not only child window may have HTSYSMENU, top-level window may have HTSYSMENU also :), 2) child window can't have menubar (HTMENU area),  3) but child window has window menu (system menu) in HTSYSMENU, please try LEFT click, this is standard behaviour also.

Comment: Thanks for the "-1", of course it is a strong argument, Jonathan

Comment: There is no example of the thing you think the text means, because that thing doesn't exist and is not what the text means. It means the system menu area, i.e. the top-left icon that displays the system icon. In the Windows 3 era that was the close button, and the documentation just hasn't been updated (other threads on the web back this up).

Comment: @Leo Davidson: Totally agree with you, but one question remains: why modern MSDN/SDK describes a non-existent thing, without specifying that this thing a long time ago does not exist?

Comment: Microsoft documentation is notoriously bad and often out of date. This should not be seen as unusual.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter: then redirect your "-1" to MSDN :)

Comment: Why do you assume the -1 was me?

Comment: Okay, I do not care :)